# What happens when actual and extern types are different?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, extern

I have two files:

## a.c

```
extern char *s;
int main()
{
    puts(s);
}
```

## and b.c:

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

I compile both of them at same time, there's no error. But program crashes when run. Why? What part of the C language specification says that this is illegal?

Comment: If the `extern char *s;` was in a header file (the usual coding style) and included in both `a.c` and `b.c`, likely your compiler would warn about that,  maybe with "...  conflicting types  for 's' - Invalid    redeclaration of 's'"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You invoked *undefined behavior* and the program *happened* to crash.

Quote from [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type

> 1 Two types have compatible type if their types are the same. Additional rules for
>   determining whether two types are compatible are described in 6.7.2 for type specifiers,
>   in 6.7.3 for type qualifiers, and in 6.7.5 for declarators. [...]
>
> 2 All declarations that refer to the same object or function shall have compatible type;
>   otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

In typical environment, when the program is run, what is stored will be read as pointer because the declaration says that a pointer is there in `a.c`, but what actually is a part of string (if size of pointers is 4 bytes) and it has little chance of being valid pointer. Therefore, reading from that address has a big chance of causing a Segmentation Fault.

Comment: If, in a.c, I had used:

char s1[] = "hello";
char *s = s1;

int main()
{
        puts(s);
}

 that works. Why does it not work with the extern?

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. The code works [with extern](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/uvd4z9ncFkoiFglQ), too.

Comment: @Sandeep: arrays are not pointers.  In your revised code in the comments, you've defined `s` as a `char *` and used it as a `char *` and initialized it with a valid `char *` so all is fine.  In the question, you've fibbed to the compiler; you told it that `s` was a `char *` but actually it is an array of `char`, and the crash is the compiler's way of telling you it hates being told lies.

Comment: @MikeCAT, I can assure you,the original program crashes.

Comment: This question has been answered in [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr1.html). But rules are spelled out in section as 6.7.5 of the C spec, as mentioned above. Therefore marking this as the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to actually know **why** it **does** crash (as opposed to why it shouldn't work):

An array is a sequence of things in memory. So with

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

the memory layout for this variable will look like this (let's say it starts at 0x00123400 with 4-byte pointers):

```
0x00123400:  'h'     <- address of s
0x00123401:  'e'
0x00123402:  'l'
0x00123403:  'l'
0x00123404:  'o'
0x00123405:  '\0'
```

To get the address of the string, it just uses the fixed number 0x00123400.

A pointer holds the address of something else. If you had:

```
char *s = "hello";
```

then the compiler would place the array "hello" somewhere, and then fill s with its address:

```
0x00123400:  0x00     <- address of s
0x00123401:  0x56
0x00123402:  0x78
0x00123403:  0x9A

0x0056789A: 'h'      <- what s points to
0x0056789B: 'e'
0x0056789C: 'l'
0x0056789D: 'l'
0x0056789E: 'o'
0x0056789F: '\0'
```

To get the address of the string, it starts from the fixed number 0x00123400, and reads the number at that location.

Now, if your variable is actually a `char[]` and you told the compiler it was a `char*`, it's going to treat it as a pointer. That means it's going to start from the address of the variable, read the number there, and use that number as the address of the string.

What number is that? Well, I did say:

```
0x00123400:  'h'     <- address of s
0x00123401:  'e'
0x00123402:  'l'
0x00123403:  'l'
```

but that's a lie - we all know memory only stores numbers, not letters. It's just shorthand so people don't have to memorize the ASCII table. What's *really* stored there is:

```
0x00123400:  0x68     <- address of s
0x00123401:  0x65
0x00123402:  0x6C
0x00123403:  0x6C
```

So your program will read the 0x68656C6C, then it will try to print the string starting from address 0x68656C6C, which is most likely an invalid address.

(Note: I'm ignoring endianness in this answer)